# Помогите новичку с объктами

Tags: java, объекты

Есть объект-товар их много и они разные(создаются по шаблону product(вино,пиво, вода и т д)) и есть покупатель, у товара есть количество(данного товара в наличии), как покупателем покупать товары(но не одного типа а разные) - то есть я не могу понять как работать с объектами, покажите хоть какой то пример, заранее благодарю!

```
package product;

public class Product {

    private String Name;
    private Double PurchasePrice;
    private String Group;
    private String Amount;
    private String Composition;
    private int Count;

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public Double getPurchasePrice() {
        return PurchasePrice;
    }

    public String getGroup() {
        return Group;
    }

    public String getAmount() {
        return Amount;
    }

    public String getComposition() {
        return Composition;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return Count;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public void setPurchasePrice(Double purchasePrice) {
        PurchasePrice = purchasePrice;
    }

    public void setGroup(String group) {
        Group = group;
    }

    public void setAmount(String amount) {
        Amount = amount;
    }

    public void setComposition(String composition) {
        Composition = composition;
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        Count = count;
    }
}

public class Shopper {
    public Shopper() {
        make_a_purchase();
    }
//тут я пытаюсь что то купить
    public void make_a_purchase(){
        System.out.println("buy...");
        for (int i = 0; i < amount_purchase(); i++){

        }
    }
//это количество случайных товаров
    int amount_purchase(){
        int amount = 0 + (int)Math.random() * 10;
        return amount;
    }
}
```

Comment: Очень советую почитать [вот это](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/index.html). Есть там и примеры, думаю после прочтения все станет ясно.

Answer (score -1):

Для того чтобы понять данный пример (псевдокод) Вам необходимо знать, что такой наследование и полиморфизм. Это можно найти [сдесь](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/index.html).

```
public abstract class БазовыйКлассДляТоваров {

    private static int количествоТовара;
    private int цена;

    пополнитьЗапас(БазовыйКлассДляТоваров товар);
    // setters and getters
}

public class Вода extends БазовыйКлассДляТовара {
    // поля
    // getters and setters
}

public class Покупатель {

    private int количествоДенег;
    private String имяПокупателя;
    private ArrayList<БазовыйКлассДляТовара> корзина;

    купитьТовар(БазовыйКлассДляТовара товар, int количествоТовара) {
        количествоДенег = количествоДенег - товар.получитьЦену * количествоТовара;
        корзина.add(товар);
    }
    // getters and setters
}
```

Идея заключается в следующем. Есть базовый класс для товаров (это как бы шаблон), он содержит общую информацию о товаре (поля) и что с этим товаром можно делать, например пополнить его запас или выкинуть просроченый товар (это уже методы). Дальше для каждого товара делаете чертеж (blueprint) или проще говоря пищете класс, а, допустим, конкретная бутылка воды - это уже обьект. Ну и последний штрих это класс для покупателя. У него есть определенная сумма денег (поле), а также он может купить товар (это метод). Можно придумать допустим, украсть товар)) При этом в корзину его добавить, а деньги не снимать. Важно! В метод купитьТовар я передаю абстрактный класс БазовыйКлассДляТовара (аюстрактный потому что это шаблон). При наследовании в этот метод можно будет передать любой товар (конкретный класс, допустим Вода) - это назымается "полиморфизм". Думаю стало немного понятнее)). 
    Еще можно разделять конкретных покупателей. Для этого класс Покупатель сделаем абстрактным и напишем следующие классы:

```
public class БольшойДядя extends Покупатель {
    // какие-то поля
    приказатьОхранеКупитьТовар(БазовыйКлассДляТовара товар, int количествоТовара);
}

public class ПростойБизнесмен extends Покупатель  {
    // какие-то поля
    приехатьНаМашинеИкупитьТовар(БазовыйКлассДляТовара товар, int количествоТовара);
}

public class БеднаяБабушка extends Покупатель {
    private int скоростьПередвижения;

    потратитьПоследниеДеньгиНаТовар(БазовыйКлассДляТовара товар, int количествоТовара);
}
```

Comment: невозможно читать. лучше отредактируйте.

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, то ваш пример с абстрактным классом в корне неправильный. Модификатор `private` для полей родителя, которые будут использованы в дочерних классах недопустимо. Для этого используется `protected` модификатор. Да и `static` свойство недопустимо в абстрактном классе, т.к. оно становится статичным для всех дочерних экземпляров. Т.е. объявив значение в одном дочернем объекте оно же будет таким же и в другом. Ваш пример больше подходит исключительно для одиночного объекта. В примере автора используется множество объектов. Поправьте, если ошибаюсь.